# How do I "backup" files and folders in /home/ when I add,remove and reorganize files/folders to /home/?

Tags: linux, backup, home

I use grsync to "backup" my home directory. But I dont understand how to use grsync to save files and dirs to a "backup". My "backup" wont be a mirror of /home/ because I might want to keep a file or folder on the backup but want to remove it from my /home/. I might want to reorganize /home/ by moving files or folders to other directories without causing duplicate files or folders on the backup after I rerun grsync. How can I accomplish having a "storage" of my files and folders with grsync or other program that will do the job with less work than doing a copy ?

Comment: Sorry that this is too complicated for you. Please remove the question.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea about graphical tools, but using terminal, you can mount your storage directory and append it to your `/etc/fstab` in your local machine, so anything you write, create or modify would be written in your Storage machine/server. So you won't be in need of removing anything if you want to save it on the Storage, and nothing would waste your local machine's storage and it's directly using the storage machine.

But if it's not a personal scenario, I recommend you have at least 2 Servers and run GlusterFS distributed replicated volume on both, your clients on the same servers. [Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/312178/glusterfs-replicated-volume-mounting-issue) you can see what problems I had with GlusterFS and you can read the solution provided.

rsync is a great and powerful tool, but I think the above solutions would help you more.